# How to get days difference using European calendar in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

I have two datepickers with European date formats:

```
function SetDatePicker() {

     $("#cphBody_txtDateFrom").attr('readonly', 'readonly');
     $("#cphBody_txtDateTo").attr('readonly', 'readonly');

     $("#cphBody_txtDateFrom, #cphBody_txtDateTo").datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonth: 1
     });
}
```

I have a JavaScript logic that validates date difference between 2 USA Dates and fails if it is more than 30:

```
   function ValidateDateDiff(sender, args) {
        var dateFrom = $('#cphBody_txtDateFrom').val();
        var dateTo = $('#cphBody_txtDateTo').val();

        var dayDiff = DaysBetween(dateFrom, dateTo);


        if (dayDiff > 30) {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }

    function DaysBetween(from, to) {

        var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        return (treatAsUTC(to) - treatAsUTC(from)) / millisecondsPerDay;
    }

    //accounting for changes to the UTC offset when Daylight Saving Time begins or ends
    function treatAsUTC(date) {
        var result = new Date(date);
        result.setMinutes(result.getMinutes() - result.getTimezoneOffset());
        return result;
    }
```

Now, I need to change the logic to validate day difference for European time standard.

What do I have to change in my logic to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by creating new function:

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/');
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[1]-1, mdy[0])
}
```

and changed a logic to get `dayDiff` value inside of `ValidateDateDiff` function:

```
var dayDiff = DaysBetween(parseDate(dateFrom), parseDate(dateTo));
```